# Simplest way to respawn configured number of instances of a specific process

Tags: linux, monitoring, redhat, process

So we have an app. which we wan to run multiple instance of it in linux. The number should be configurable. We also want that whenever one of the instance disappears, a new one is booted up.

I was looking into C based programs, shell script, python script etc. but I was wondering what would be the most simple, easiest way to do it.  Are there any tools out there? Can one simply use some linux built-in functionality?

Linux distribution is Red Hat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is the tool for the job. With monit, you can control a lot of variables and act upon changes. More info [here](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html).